# Best way to denote possibility of refreshing an image which is embedded in text in Android

Tags: gui-design, android, image, refresh

In an Android application, I have to display images during texts. For example:
[image]

So image must be a part of text without border, shadow, ... or with `button` effect. Problem is that sometimes image does not load properly, for example:

[image]

Now I have to denote that image is refresh-able by clicking it. How I can denote this with keeping image as part of text?

***Edit***

- Really above problem occurs at run-time and my application cannot detect loaded/generated image is incomplete, else it could try for reloading/regenerating.
- My application is a `Flashcard Application`
  [image]
- a card may contain more than one image

Comment: Is it impossible to solve the loading problem? That's ultimately the solution that would provide the best user experience.

Comment: could you provide more context? like a screenshot of the page where it would be embebed in

Comment: @AlejandroVeltri I edited my question, please see it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could blur out or change opacity to low on the icon that is semi-loaded; and then added a refresh icon on top of that with more prominent colour, like black to dark grey.

See a simple example below.

[image]

Of course, colouring, opacity and exact size and positioning of the refresh icon is up to your eyes.

PS:
As someone mentioned in the comments, fixing the loading issue would probably be your unltimate solution indeed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but as I discussed in edition of my question, really above problem occurs at run-time and my application cannot detect loaded/generated image is incomplete, else it could try for reloading/regenerating.

Answer (score 0):

#### I'm sure you already know, but I have to say it:

First and foremost, the loading problem is the issue that really should be addressed. I'm not sure where these images are coming from, if they're being incorrectly generated, or why they're rendering when only partially loaded, but this is ultimately the issue that needs to be solved. Users have experienced long load times and can be adequately prepared for that (loading indicators, image placeholders, lower quality images that get replaced with hi-res, etc...), but half-loaded images is unexpected, so a user wouldn't necessarily be ready to handle that.

#### Until you fix the real loading issue, I'd suggest simply reporting it as an error.

However your app reports errors, I'd follow the same pattern and show that some images failed to load. Provide the user with a way to trigger a reload, preferably one that requests all failed images so they don't have to find and tap each failed image.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUeS7s.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added more details. Please see my question again.

Comment: @ Also you talked in about `image placeholder`. Do you think `OBJECT REPLACEMENT CHARACTER (U+FFFC)` is a good candidate?

Comment: @hasanghaforian Would you be able to use a placeholder if you can't detect if the image loaded successfully? I think you should ask this question with additional technical details at StackOverflow and try to solve the loading issue.

Comment: I mean I can display an `image placeholder` (for example (`U+FFFC`) before loading and displaying image without knowing if image loading was successful or not.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried regenerating the images after the first content load occurs ? 
Eg: You load the content and some images are not completely loaded. You do a background reload of all images. Based on cache and other factors the reload should happen faster and issues of the images should be solved. 
As there is no way to know if the image is loaded or not this would be your best take on the issue.

Else you could ask the user if the images are loaded or not and prompt him to reload. But this implies that you either add placeholders where images are or the user won't really know where to expect an image or not.

[image]